# ToolStripMenuItem has no Popup event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm reading through [this book](http://imcs.dvfu.ru/lib.int/docs/Languages/C-Sharp/Windows%20Forms%20Programming%20With%20C%23.pdf) on creating Windows Forms with Visual Studio C# Express 2013, and I got to page 93 in the book (129 in the pdf), and it started to make use of a "Popup" event on their ToolStripMenuItem. For some reason, it doesn't seem to be present in my ToolStripMenuItem. In case something changed between versions, the Popup event is the event that is activated once when the menu item is first displayed.

What's going on? Is it because I'm using a newer version of C# than the book? If so, what's the equivalent event I'm looking for?

Comment: Can you  place some code in your question?

Comment: The book is from 2002, only .NET 1.0 was around back then and there was no ToolStripMenuItem yet.  Not until 2005, version 2.0.  Otherwise a good hint that stealing copyrighted work does not pay off.  You can't learn good programming from this book, it is entirely too old.

Comment: I second @HansPassant 's advice: This book is totally outdated! 2002 was shortly after Windows XP was released,and when Bill Gates himself announced the first version of .NET ! I met him in person at this time at a developers conference! So please forget it and buy yourself a book which is up-to-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MainMenu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mainmenu%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [MenuItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) classes are replaced by [MenuStrip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ToolStripMenuItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem(v=vs.110).aspx) but they are retained for both backward compatibility and future use if you choose.

you can change the designer code so you can follow the tutorial or you can use `DropDownClosed`, `DropDownOpened` and `DropDownOpening` events in new classes.